# Mac 10.8 + Python Scripts: How best to control the python architecture in scheduling?

Tags: python-2.7, launchd, cx-oracle

I have written a python script that queries cx_Oracle and processes the results.  Now I'm ready to schedule it on my mac OS10.8 using launchd.

As you may know, cx_Oracle on this mac OS requires unweildy solutions to control the bitness of the python that runs the .py script.  These solutions range from lipoing your python (on the install or in the virtual environment) to specifying the bitness manually when you run the script, e.g. "arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.7 scriptname.py".

I have read through the plist documentation, and as far as I can tell, you can't specify bitness as part of the plist configuration.  Perhaps you could in the Info.plist file that applies to python, but then it would apply to every .py script you schedule.  In which case you might as well only have a 32 or 64 bit python install.

Understanding that my goal is schedule scripts and specify per script the bitness of the python that runs it, what would you recommend?  Is there something easy I'm overlooking?  Your advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you can specify bitness manually in shell, you can also specify it in a shell script, right? If so, you can just run the shell script with launchd. Also you could probably just put `arch ... python scriptname.py` directly into plist. Also you can specify VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes in plist environment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  I didn't think of running the shell that calls the python script instead of just running the python script itself.  The "Also you could probably just put arch ... python scriptname.py directly into plist." is the solution I hoped to find, but I don't think it's possible. Is "specify VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes" something i can do on a per-job basis in individual plists, or does it go into Info.plist and force all python scripts to be scheduled using 32 bit python?  Thx again.

Comment: See `EnvironmentVariables` in [launchd.plist](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html) man page. It can be on a per-job  basis. As for putting 'arch' directly into plist file, why it's not possible? `arch` is just a program, the rest is argument list and you can specify arguments in plist files, anyway just try it and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and post what works.

Comment: Also make sure you use `ProgramArguments` key, not `Program`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10712484/521590) answer for example.  It if doesn't work (single string), try array of strings like [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/8179).

Comment: I tried many permutations of ProgramArguments last night, using arrays like inline ` <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array> 
  <string>arch</string>
  <string>-386</string>
  <string>/Users/me/Documents/Python_Alerts_Project/launchpythontest.sh</string>
 </array>`  .  These don't seem to have any effect.  I tried putting the `#!/bin/sh
/bin/sh arch -i386 /usr/bin/python2.7 /Users/me/Documents/Python_Alerts_Project/sqlalchemytrial2.py` in a .sh shell and calling that from plist. No joy.  Perhaps the fundamental goal is to make launchd execute the script using the "terminal" environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/library/LaunchAgents/local.arch.plist`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>local.arch</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/arch</string>
        <string>-i386</string>
        <string>/usr/bin/python2.7</string>
        <string>/volumes/ramdisk/arch.py</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`/volumes/ramdisk/arch.py`:

```
import sys

with open('/volumes/ramdisk/python.arch.log', 'a') as f:
    f.write('sys.maxsize = %s\n' % sys.maxsize)
```

In terminal:

```
$ launchctl load ~/library/LaunchAgents/local.arch.plist
$ launchctl start local.arch
$ # arch -i386, 32-bit
$ cat /volumes/ramdisk/python.arch.log
sys.maxsize = 2147483647
$ # no arch, 64-bit
$ /usr/bin/python2.7 -c 'import sys; print(sys.maxsize)'
9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and repeated responses on this item.  Implementing your directions, I was able to put architecture-related errors for cx_Oracle to rest...and move on to what I think are a new set of unrelated errors :).  W/o your explicit example I'm not sure how long I would have gone before I realized that the program has to be fully qualified by its path.